# Trying to mod MC Forge 1.12.2, but SetupDecompWorkspace not working

Tags: java, minecraft-forge

I am trying to make a mod for Minecraft Forge 1.12.2, mdk file forge-1.12.2-14.23.5.2854-mdk. Problem is, when i right-click inside this folder, open Powershell and run the *./gradlew setupDecompWorkspace eclipse* command, it comes up with an error log:

forge-1.12.2-14.23.5.2854-mdk> ./gradlew setupDecompWorkspace eclipse                                                                                                     To honour the JVM settings for this build a new JVM will be forked. Please consider using the daemon: https://docs.gradlDaemon will be stopped at the end of the build stopping after processing

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring root project 'forge-1.12.2-14.23.5.2854-mdk'.

> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'.
> Could not resolve net.minecraftforge.gradle:ForgeGradle:3.+.
> Required by:
> project :
> > Failed to list versions for net.minecraftforge.gradle:ForgeGradle.
> > Unable to load Maven meta-data from https://files.minecraftforge.net/maven/net/minecraftforge/gradle/ForgeGradle/maven-metadata.xml.
> > Could not get resource 'https://files.minecraftforge.net/maven/net/minecraftforge/gradle/ForgeGradle/maven-metadata.xml'.
> > Could not GET 'https://files.minecraftforge.net/maven/net/minecraftforge/gradle/ForgeGradle/maven-metadata.xml'.
> > sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
> > Failed to list versions for net.minecraftforge.gradle:ForgeGradle.
> > Unable to load Maven meta-data from https://jcenter.bintray.com/net/minecraftforge/gradle/ForgeGradle/maven-metadata.xml.
> > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/net/minecraftforge/gradle/ForgeGradle/maven-metadata.xml'.
> > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/net/minecraftforge/gradle/ForgeGradle/maven-metadata.xml'.
> > sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
> > Failed to list versions for net.minecraftforge.gradle:ForgeGradle.
> > Unable to load Maven meta-data from https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/net/minecraftforge/gradle/ForgeGradle/maven-metadata.xml.
> > Could not get resource 'https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/net/minecraftforge/gradle/ForgeGradle/maven-metadata.xml'.
> > Could not GET 'https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/net/minecraftforge/gradle/ForgeGradle/maven-metadata.xml'.
> > sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 6s

Could somebody please help me with this? I am not sure what else to try.

Comment: Possibly helpful: https://forums.minecraftforge.net/topic/82543-1152-gradle-build-fail/?do=findComment&comment=390793 " The issue is that whatever JDK you're using does not have LetsEncrypt's root certificate. Be sure you are using jdk-8.0.242.08-hotspot or newer"

Comment: does it have to have the '-hotspot' on the end of the filename? @sorifiend

Comment: as long as you download from the oracle JDK or OpenJDK then it will be ok.

Answer (score 0):

(Couldn't make a comment because not enough reputation) They might have changed the way how you should set up your mod environment. According to their instructions, you should first run the command `gradlew genEclipseRuns`, which will generate the `runClient` and `runServer` configurations that will allow you to click the "Run" button in eclipse. After that, you should run the command `gradlew eclipse`. This should set up your Eclipse folder. What I usually do after that is go into Eclipse, go to **File**, then **Import**, then in the search bar search for **Existing Gradle Projects**. Put in the directory text box the directory of the Forge MDK you have extracted, and click done. It should start importing the necessary libraries needed. After that, you are all set.

It seems that the links that Forge is trying to extract data from are outdated because if you try clicking on them they lead to a `404 Error`. (The file must have been deleted).