# Unable to create New 1.12 Forge MC mod in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, gradle, minecraft-forge

I followed the instructions in the [Forge documentation](https://mcforge.readthedocs.io/en/1.12.x/gettingstarted/), but I got the error in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63461573/trying-to-mod-mc-forge-1-12-2-but-setupdecompworkspace-not-working/72071838#72071838). I followed the instructions in the answer to the post, running `gradlew genEclipseRuns`, then `gradlew eclipse`. I then imported my project into Eclipse as the answer in the post said, but the ExampleMod.java file is filled with errors saying that various symbols cannot be resolved. Does anyone know how to make it so the mod can actually see the libraries it needs? I am running Windows 10.
Thanks!
[image: ExampleMod.java screenshot with errors]

Comment: If you just run `gradlew setupDecompWorkspace` followed by `gradlew build`, without involving Eclipse at all, do you get a working mod file?

Comment: No. it says that there is no command "setupDecompWorkspace" (I don't know the exact error that was given because I don't have the computer in front of me right now)

Comment: Okay, in that case your problem is unrelated to Eclipse. Next time you're at your computer, you should edit your question to include the exact error that gives you.

Comment: Ok. I ran it again. It says: `FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Task 'setupDecompWorkspace' not found in root project 'mcmod1'.`

Comment: Did you download the 1.12 MDK zip? Did you run that command in the directory you unzipped it in?

Comment: I unziped the 1.12.2 Recommended MDK, then I copied all of the contents of the new folder into a new folder (mcmod1), then cd-ed into mcmod1, then ran that command and got that error. Is it the copying into a new directory that caused a problem? I did copy all the hidden files too.

Answer (score 0):

Forge changed their required procedure without bothering to update their documentation. Import it as a Gradle project instead of just importing the folder.

Comment: I tried doing `gradlew setupDecompWorkspace` (failed), then `gradlew build` (failed), `gradlew genEclipseRuns` (success), then `gradlew eclipse` (success), then `gradlew build` again (failed). Then I tried to import it into Eclipse as a Gradle project, but it still had the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I've hade some issues as well. I ended up deleting everything gradle and related in every folder I could find it in. I then reunzipped the mdk into a fresh (recreated directory) and ran 'gradlew genEclipseRuns' then 'gradlew eclipse'. That allowed me to manually import the project into eclipse. Afterwards I built my project in eclipse, then went to the project folder and ran 'gradlew build'. That seems to work.